# HTTP Accept-Encoding and sending unencoded data

Tags: encoding, http-headers

I building a module for compressing HTTP output. Reading the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), I haven't found a clear distinction on a couple of things:

`Accept-Encoding:`

**Should this be treated the same as a `Accept-Encoding: *` or as if no header is present?**

Or what if I don't support gzip, but I get a header like this:

`Accept-Encoding: gzip`

**Should I return a 406 error or just return the data unencoded?**

EDIT:

I've read over the spec a few times. It mentions my first case, but it doesn't define what the behavior of the server should be.

Should I treat this case as if the header is not present? Or should I return a 406 error  because there's no way to encode something given the field value ('' isn't a valid encoding).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is written everything in the [Spec: 14.3 Accept-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> The special "*" symbol in an Accept-Encoding field matches any
>            available content-coding not explicitly listed in the header
>            field.
>
> If an Accept-Encoding field is present in a request, and if the server cannot send a response which is acceptable according to the Accept-Encoding header, then the server SHOULD send an error response with the 406 (Not Acceptable) status code.

edit:

> If the Accept-Encoding field-value is empty, then only the "identity"
>            encoding is acceptable.
>
> In this case, if "identity" is one of the available content-codings, then the server SHOULD use the "identity" content-coding, unless it has additional information that a different content-coding is meaningful to the client.

[What is "identity"](http://www.web-polygraph.org/docs/userman/compression.html)

> **identity**
>       The default (identity) encoding; the use of no transformation whatsoever. This content-coding is used only in the Accept- Encoding header, and SHOULD NOT be used in the Content-Encoding header.

Comment: I think you missed my point. If I have an Accept-Encoding field, but it is empty, is that treated like a * symbol or should I return a 406 error?

Comment: `If I have an Accept-Encoding field, but it is empty`. Is that not clear? I don't think the spec specifies...

Comment: Sorry, you are right, its late... But there is written something about the "identity" encoding, I edit my answer

Comment: What is the "identity" encoding? Does this mean whatever the file was initially without any change whatsoever?

Comment: I think its the server default value, which you can set in the config of the webserver (apache for example)

Comment: @timashew- That last snippet is exactly what I was looking for. As for my second question, I'll make that customizable. Thanks!